# Why strings with diacritics doesn't work properly? Any solution?

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I don't know a lot about scripting. In Logitech Gaming Software I wanted to use this LUA script:

```
function OnEvent(event, family)
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2) then  
        PlayMacro("DPI Up")
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 2) then
        PlayMacro("DPI Down")
    end
end
```

It should increase my mouse DPI when I'm pressing RMB and decrease it when I'll release RMB, but value in brackets (after `PlayMacro`) should be in language I use (Polish).
In Polish you write "DPI w górę" instead of "DPI Up" and "DPI w dół" instead of "DPI Down", but then script doesn't work.
I'm pretty sure it's all about diacritics because for example "Back" macro works fine - in Polish you write "Wstecz" <- word without diacritics, I also checked words like "Zmiana DPI" and all works properly with them (because they are without diactric marks I guess).

What can I do to make the script works properly?

Comment: It could be related to the text encoding used in a profile and how texts from Lua scripts is treated. Lua by itself is charset-agnostic, so LGS might treat strings from scripts as either acscii, or as utf-8. Any issues might be a result of that mistreat, but I couldn't find any info about charsets/encoding used in LGS.

Comment: Try UTF8 encoding: `"DPI w g\195\179r\196\153"` instead of `"DPI w górę"` and `"DPI w d\195\179\197\130"` instead of `"DPI w dół"`

Comment: It works! Before creating this thread I was thinking that maybe I can type characters codes instead of just characters, but I didn't know in which standard (Unicode etc.) and how to separate them, now it's all clear. 
Thank you all! Problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
local UTF8_letters = {["ó"] = "\195\179", ["ę"] = "\196\153", ["ł"] = "\197\130"}

local function UTF8(str)
   return (str:gsub(".", UTF8_letters))
end

function OnEvent(event, family)
    if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 2) then  
        PlayMacro(UTF8"DPI w górę")
    elseif (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 2) then
        PlayMacro(UTF8"DPI w dół")
    end
end
```

Comment: This one doesn't work. I don't know why. Anyway, your first answer ("Try UTF8 encoding [...]") solved my problem, so thank you again ! :)

Comment: remember that `.` is a single *ascii* character, so if `'ó'` is a multibyte sequence, `.` won't match it (but will match its bytes separately).

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - as far as I understood, the problem is to use UTF-8 strings in a Lua script written in 1-byte Windows encoding.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff you're mostly right, except that we don't know the encoding. OP never tells us (and probably doesn't know) what werid encoding the code editor uses to encode those characters, and for all we know it's some windows-specific multibyte bull\*\*\*\*, so we can't make any assumptions.

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer - Polish Windows has only 2 encodings: single-byte (windows-1250) and double-byte (UTF-16LE).  It's obvious that it can't be UTF-16 (because Lua is unable to correctly compile script encoded with UTF-16). Hence, OP works with windows-1250.